# Best way to get data chunk from recorded wav audio javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, signal-processing, audio-recording

I'm looking for the most straightforward means of recording audio in javascript and extracting the data chunk from the recording. The data chunk of a wav file is a chunk of data that includes an array of either 8, 16 or 32 bit samples which represent the amplitude of the sine wave defining the sound at discrete intervals, along with a block that signifies the length of this array and another block that tells the computer it is looking at the data chunk of the file (the main thing I want is that array.)

I have found audio visualizers that utilize this data and I could hack one of them and trace how they're pulling it out of the file, but this... sounds like a nightmare. lol I was wondering if anyone on here had any experience with this sort of thing and could point me toward a more straight forward means of doing what I want to do.

One liner: I'd like to be able to record audio through a web browser and get the data chunk from the audio.

Comment: Have you seen this library? https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

Comment: hmm... no, this does not appear to be one that I've looked at. Thanks!